# How to turn on autoformat pasted strings in DataGrip?

Tags: edit, datagrip

Previously, I inserted lines containing \n into the editor, and the following content was automatically wrapped to a new query line. After new installation it's not working, so hundreds of saved sql requests are hard to work with.

inserting

```
select * \n    from smth
```

need after insert:

```
select * 
    from smth
```

I've searched through settings but did not found any appropriate checkbox. Google not helped though.

Comment: What version did you use before? Did you use any custom plugin? Is "\n" visually typed in code source?

Answer (score 0):

DataGrip doesn't support it.

Use *Reformat Code* action to format your query